# optimized container for dict with typed items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a large (typed) array from a dataset with the first column containing a unique key to index each row, and the other columns containing matrices or vectors of known size. I there any standard way or a library to efficiently turn that into a hash map for key based retrieval? Splitting the row into individual key-value objects doesn't seem very memory efficient.

Here is the baseline sub-optimal solution:

```
arr = np.array([
    ('b0263', 'a', 1, 2, 3),
    ('26ab0', 'b', 4, 5, 6),
    ('6d7fc', 'c', 7, 8, 9),
    ('48a24', 'd', 0, 1, 2),
    ('1dcca', 'e', 3, 4, 5)],
    dtype="S5, c, i4, i4, i4")
out = {key: values for key, *values in arr}
```

I thought about a dict containing the integer indexes of the corresponding rows but it requires two levels of indexing.

Comment: Show us a sample array and some code which you've already tried.

Comment: "Splitting the row into individual key-value pairs doesn't seem very efficient." But, why not? Key lookups are O(1), and your array values stay typed, with all the goodness that comes with it.

Comment: Textual based explanation doesn't make sense here! Show us what data you are talking about!

Comment: Splitting the rows is not memory efficient because it makes a multitude of small individual objects each carrying the metadata about shape, type, etc.

Comment: Your array isn't an array. And it isn't typed. What do you even mean by "typed"? You've tagged this with numpy, does that have something to do with it? What, *exactly* are you dealing with, and what is your desired output?

Comment: I have updated the description of the data and the example. As I wrote, my desired output is a container that doesn't store the rows separately.

Comment: Oh, you have a structured numpy array. There is no hashmap implementation that I know of that could do this. Your original idea of just mapping the keys to indices is probably the best way to go, if memory efficiency is a concern.

Comment: is space really a big concern? If not, this seems like a very inefficient way of storing things if you plan to operate on them. Why not a dataframe?

Comment: I just started looking up the Pandas documentation. I never felt the need to use pandas over numpy before, but it looks like a good candidate indeed.

Comment: it will allow you to create the first column as index instead as well, essentially giving you just about everything you need.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh FYI, pandas doesn't seem to take advantage of indexes with an arbitrary dtype (see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19609). One can try to [hack around this limitation](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19609#issuecomment-356857733) or fall back to a generic object type index which is probably as slow as the two-level indexing solution mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Your structured array:

```
In [317]: arr                                                                        
Out[317]: 
array([(b'b0263', b'a', 1, 2, 3), (b'26ab0', b'b', 4, 5, 6),
       (b'6d7fc', b'c', 7, 8, 9), (b'48a24', b'd', 0, 1, 2),
       (b'1dcca', b'e', 3, 4, 5)],
      dtype=[('f0', 'S5'), ('f1', 'S1'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<i4')])
```

The first field:

```
In [318]: arr['f0']                                                                  
Out[318]: array([b'b0263', b'26ab0', b'6d7fc', b'48a24', b'1dcca'], dtype='|S5')
```

A dictionary built from that array:

```
In [321]: dd = {k:v for k,v in zip(arr['f0'], arr)}                                  
In [322]: dd                                                                         
Out[322]: 
{b'b0263': (b'b0263', b'a', 1, 2, 3),
 b'26ab0': (b'26ab0', b'b', 4, 5, 6),
 b'6d7fc': (b'6d7fc', b'c', 7, 8, 9),
 b'48a24': (b'48a24', b'd', 0, 1, 2),
 b'1dcca': (b'1dcca', b'e', 3, 4, 5)}
In [323]: dd[b'6d7fc']                                                               
Out[323]: (b'6d7fc', b'c', 7, 8, 9)
```

In this construction, the value of a dictionary element is an element of the original array.

It has `type` `np.void` and `dtype`:

```
In [329]: dd[b'6d7fc'].dtype                                                         
Out[329]: dtype([('f0', 'S5'), ('f1', 'S1'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<i4')])
```

And it is actually a `view` of the original (I checked `__array_interface__`).  So apart from the pointers/references it doesn't consume much additional memory.

Recent `numpy` versions have be reworking the handling of views/copies of structured arrays, so the details may have changed, especially with respect to multifield references.

I should qualify the memory comment.  In this example, `itemsize` is just 18.  But referencing an element of the array, `arr[0]` creates a new `np.void` object.  I suspect that object overhead is larger than 18 bytes.

You could create a dictionary with tuple values:

```
In [335]: dd = {k:v.tolist()[1:] for k,v in zip(arr['f0'], arr)}                     
In [336]: dd[b'b0263']                                                               
Out[336]: (b'a', 1, 2, 3)
```